# Sampled data plot doesnt make sense

Tags: signal-analysis, frequency-domain, time-domain

I've measured an accoustic signal for approx. 90 seconds with a sample frequency of 192 kHz (Note: the used device can sample data with maximaly 192 kHz, therefore i am not 100% certain, what sample frequency was ultimately used) and the result was a ≈17000000 big sampled data. I want to extract system-specific frequencies that i know nothing about (e. g. what frequency range they lie in).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fs = 192000  #IMP23ABSU
dt = 1.0 / fs
x = pd.read_csv(directory + file)
n = len(x)  # number of samples
t = np.arange(0, n) / fs  # time range for data
fig, (time_domain, frequency_domain) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(80, 60))
time_domain.plot(t, x.MIC)
time_domain.set_xlabel('Time')
time_domain.set_ylabel('Measured accustic signal')

y = np.fft.fft(x)
f_increment = fs / n
f = np.arange(0, n) * f_increment
frequency_domain.plot(f, abs(y)**2/n)
frequency_domain.set_xlabel('Frequency / Hz')
frequency_domain.set_ylabel('Amplitude')
```

The output looks like this
[image]
The output is not what i expected; i thought that i would get a plot with magnitudes and a few given frequencies that describe the measured accustic sound. What am i missing here?

EDIT: As pointed out by a few comments this needed a bit more information. Im expecting specific frequencies in a range of 0-10 kHz. This is based on a few read studies regarding this topic. Furthermore, i corrected the DFT plot and uploaded a 1 new screenshots of the zoomed in result:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t the input to the fft call be x.MIC?

Comment: If you the data doesn't meet your expectations: please explain WHAT your expectations are, WHY you expect this and HOW the data that you see is different. You claim that you  expect "a few given frequencies that describe the measured accustic sound."  but you don't explain why you expect this.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have uploaded the missing information.

Comment: @Tom: without having a closer look at the time domain data, we can't answer this. Can you post it as a csv or wave file? A good first test is to take a listen. If it sounds like noise, than you expect a broad spectrum. If you can hear actual tones in there, than you would expect strong individual lines or peaks . You also seem to have a huge amount of energy at DC or very low frequencies. It doesn't seem to be a DC offset, so something else is causing this

Comment: I cant post any file, but i can say that it sounds like noise - not tones. Can the DC offset be caused by the beginning of the measurement which is done by pressing a button?

Comment: @Tom: the spectrum sure looks like noise, so if it sounds like noise too than chances are it is noise and your analysis is correct. If that's not what you expect, you need to talk to the people who made the measurement.

Comment: @Hilmar: how can i tell if there is spectral leakage happening here and how would i know what windowing function to use?