# Why is numpy.angle returning values on real numbers?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

This question is a follow up on [previous](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89769/sampled-data-plot-doesnt-make-sense?noredirect=1#comment193024_89769). As I am analyzing the sampled data I need to know if it is **complex or real**. This is important for me since I want to transform my two-sided to a one-sided PSD. Then I have to either divide the spectrum by $N/2$ (for real-valued signals) or $N$ (for complex-valued signals).

So far I executed both `np.angle(x.MIC, deg=True)` and `np.iscomplexobj(x.MIC)` with the returned value of `array([180., 180., 180., ..., 180., 180.,   0.])` and `False` respectively.

Why do I keep getting this inconsistency in my results? Am I missing something important here?

Comment: ??? You have the time data… Does x.MIC have real or complex values?!

Comment: @Jdip complex values are not present, but angles are. How can it be real if there are angles?

Comment: Ok, I agree it’s a little confusing. I wrote an answer explaining the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.angle(z)` with `z = a + bi` uses [arctan2(a,b)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html),

> which returns the signed angle in radians between the ray ending at
> the origin and passing through the point (1,0), and the ray ending at
> the origin and passing through the point (b, a).

In your case, `b = 0` so `np.angle()` is returning `arctan2(a,0)`.

- If `a > 0`,  that means `a` lies on the positive x-axis of the unit circle, and the angle between the positive x-axis and the line connecting  `a` and the origin $(0,0)$ is `0`.
- If `a < 0`,  that means `a` lies on the **negative** x-axis of the unit circle, and the angle between the positive x-axis and the line connecting  `a` and the origin $(0,0)$ is `pi`.

Since you're asking for degrees, it multiplies the values by `180/pi`, so the final result is either `0` for positive real numbers or `180` for negative real numbers.

Comment: That solves my question. Thank you!