# Improving the Time Domain Normalization of Acoustic Sound Data

Tags: time-domain, acoustics, normalization

I have tried to evaluate the analog microphone (IMP23ABSU) built into the STEVAL-STWINKT1B with the FP-SNS-DATALOG1 (HS-Datalogger). The values were exported as "raw values" (this is an option that can be selected when executing the data logger script). According to the manufacturer, the unit of measurement is dB. Below you will find the DeviceConfig.json file used during data export with the datalogger.

```
    {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "IMP23ABSU",
                "sensorDescriptor": {
                    "subSensorDescriptor": [
                        {
                            "id": 0,
                            "sensorType": "MIC",
                            "dimensions": 1,
                            "dimensionsLabel": [
                                "aud"
                            ],
                            "unit": "Waveform",
                            "dataType": "int16_t",
                            "FS": [
                                130
                            ],
                            "ODR": [
                                8000,
                                16000,
                                32000,
                                48000,
                                96000,
                                192000
                            ],
                            "samplesPerTs": {
                                "min": 0,
                                "max": 1000,
                                "dataType": "int16_t"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "sensorStatus": {
                    "subSensorStatus": [
                        {
                            "ODR": 192000,
                            "ODRMeasured": 192000,
                            "initialOffset": 0.19303,
                            "FS": 130,
                            "sensitivity": 1,
                            "isActive": true,
                            "samplesPerTs": 1000,
                            "usbDataPacketSize": 4096,
                            "sdWriteBufferSize": 136192,
                            "wifiDataPacketSize": 0,
                            "comChannelNumber": -1,
                            "ucfLoaded": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

ST provides Python scripts for plotting, among other things. Below you can see such a plot.

[image]

According to the manufacturer, the $Y$ values are in dB, which is very unlikely at this point ($30000$ dB peak).

Now to my actual question. Do I have to normalize the $Y$-axes somehow in order to display the sampled values in a meaningful way?

(This question is followed up on a [previous one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89769/sampled-data-plot-doesnt-make-sense))

Update: The support of the manufacturer admitted their mistake saying that the units were in dB. Now the units are supposed to be in LSB over $16$ bits and since the data goes from $-32768$ to $+32768$, its up to full scale, which is $130$dB$_{SPL}$, or $0$dB$_{V}$, or $1$V. Furthermore, they said that if I wanted the LSB in volts I have to $\frac{1 V}{32768}$ or if I want them in dB$_{V}$ have to $20 \log_{10} \left(\vert volts \vert \right)$. I'm facing the another issue now (see below)

[image].

I guess I'm facing the "clipping-issue" and I have to "turn-down" the volume? Am I correct or did I plot wrong? Here is my code:

```py
    # Read in the data
    x = pd.read_csv(directory + file)
    x = x.MIC.to_numpy()
    
    # Set the parameters
    fs = 192000 / 2 #IMP23ABSU
    n = len(x)  # number of samples
    dt = 1 / fs  # sampling rate
    t = np.arange(0, n) * dt  # time range for data
    
    """Plot data in uV"""
    x_array = x.MIC.to_numpy()
    zero_indices = x_array == 0
    x_uV = np.divide(1, x_array, out=np.zeros_like(x_array), where=x_array != 0)
    
    # Plot the data
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(t, x_uV)
    plt.show()
```

EDIT: I have used a calibration mic and plotted the signal in time and frequency domain [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/90042/mems-microphone-convert-v-to-dbv-and-performing-fft). How can i determine the conversion factor?

Comment: The Datasheet of the IMP23ABSU tells me, that the mic has an acoustic overload point of 130 dBSPL (meaning it can't measure more than 130 dB without distortion). Accordingly my sampled data has to be normalized by a given factor in order for it to be in the range of 0-130 dBSPL. Am i correct? Is this to be done with peak normalization? How does this work?
The DeviceConfig.json also tells about a Full Scale (FS) factor of 130. Is this factor to be used for the normalization aswell?

Comment: The data is obviously not in dB but looks to be in linear units (but it doesn't appear to be in Pascals either). Can you quote exactly where in the documentation it says otherwise ? Sorry, in this case you just need to plow through the data sheet of the board and the firmware documentation to figure out what the A/D scaling and preamp gain is. You may be able to reverse engineer the Python scripts as well, but that depends on whether they do appropriate scaling or not.

Comment: @Hilmar Thats what i think aswell. [Here](https://community.st.com/t5/other-hardware/unit-of-measure-for-the-mems-imp23absu-microphone/m-p/604566#:~:text=The%20raw%20data%20are%20in%20dB.) is my discussion with them. I think i have to perform either **peak normalization** or **RMS normalization**, but im not sure.

Comment: @Hilmar The documentation of the IMP23ABSU can be found [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5522-ultrasound-behavior-and-guidelines-of-analog-imp23absu-mems-microphone-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and the documentation of the STEVAL - [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/data_brief/steval-stwinkt1b.pdf). I didnt find usefull information for this topic

Comment: Your data seems to be either very aggressively clipped or compressed. Are you sure this is **not** the case? Furthermore, if you have raw time data, which seems to be your case, I believe the best approach should be to use **peak normalisation**. Alternatively, you could perform some RMS calculations (most probably running RMS) and then perform **RMS normalisation** to those data. But since you have “instantaneous” values, you should do **peak normalisation**.

Comment: @ZaellixA: could also be a sweep measurement..

Comment: @Tom: if you can't figure out by plowing through the documentation you will have to calibrate the setup (which is a really good idea anyway). Capture a few sine waves with known (acoustic amplitudes) and verify that A) your signal is clean: no distortions, harmonics, etc) and B) check the gain. You can calibrate with a reference source or just using a known-good microphone setup.

Comment: @Hilmar yes, that was exactly my next approach with this. I will post my progress when im done

Comment: @Hilmar yes, this is also a possibility, thanks for bringing that up.

Comment: @Tom, I also think that you should work with known signals to be able to deduce from the output what is going on. I briefly went through the documentation too and didn’t manage to find something. As Hilmar also suggested above, going through the Python functions may also reveal what is going on. It is possible that the Python code converts the actual values to linear (from dB I assume)?

Comment: Since the manufacturer uploaded new information i tried plotting it again, but it seems either im doing something wrong, or im facing another issue.

Comment: @Tom: ZaellixA has a very good point: Do NOT trust a measurement until the whole measurement system has been fully qualified in terms noise floor, time drift, distortion, THD, SNR, etc. No measurement is perfect and if you don't know what the imperfections are, you don't know what the data is good for and what it isn't. Sorry, but making "good" physical measurements is quite difficult.