# MEMS Microphone Convert V to dBV and Performing FFT

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

At first is sampled data from the IMP23ABSU MEMS mic converted to V by multiplying each sample by the conversion factor $ \frac{1}{32786} $. Then i want to calculate the FFT and PSD after applying a passband with 20-80kHz range and windowing. Since im working with a lot of samples (around 17.538.000) it seems only right to represent the data in logarithmic scale. For that im in need of converting the data into dBV.

The mic has a sensitivity of -38 dBV ±1 dB @ 94 dBSPL, 1 kHz. If i convert the sensitivity to V i get a correction factor of 0.012589 by calculating $corr_V=10^{\frac{-38}{20}}$. How can i convert the data now to dBV using this correction factor? Do i just multiply each sample by the correction factor? How can i then represent the dBV correctly using the FFT?

This is what i have done so far

```
# ...
calib_signal_V = calibration_94dB_1kHz * (1 / 32768)
calib_signal_V_masked = np.where(calib_signal_V == 0, 10e-10, 
calib_signal_V)

# For time domain:
magnitude = 20 * np.log10(np.abs(calib_signal_V_masked))  # dBV

# apply window
N = len(calibration_94dB_1kHz)
s = signal.windows.flattop(N) * calib_signal_V_masked  
# For frequency domain
X = 2 * np.abs(np.fft.rfft(s))/N  # normalized FFT in V
X_freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(N, 1.0 / 192000)
X_dbV = 20*np.log10(X)  # normalized fft in dBV
X_dbV = -38 + X_dbV
```

I normalized the fft by the window-length and multiply by 2 since we are discarding the negative frequencies of the FFT. The mic has a full scale of 130dBSPL, or 0dBV, or 1V (because 94dBSPL = -38dBV) so i have added the -38 dBV to the signal.

And i get two warnings.

1. RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log10 **SOLVED**
2. ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part **SOLVED**

Edit: I used a Digital Sound Level Meter Calibrator 94 dB @ 1kHz and plotted the result. You can see the plots below

Edit: I added the improved code.
[image]
[image]
[image]

How can i now get the conversion factor and plot the dBV?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing. Could you please clarify what the range of the values you get is? It is not entirely clear how you convert from the initial values (which I can’t understand what they represent) to $V$, could you elaborate? The number of samples, usually, does **not** justify the use of linear or logarithmic scales, the range of their values does. So, do you want to use logarithmic scale for both $x$ and $y$ axes, or for one of them? The correction factor is just the voltage reading for a pressure of $1 \, \textrm{Pa}$ (which is $94 \, \textrm{dB}$. You have to (cont.)

Comment: (cont.’ed) have the voltage values of the samples and compare them to that to find the pressure value they represent. Finally, when “FFTing” you should make sure you scale the values correctly and then they should represent the correct amplitude (or power).

Comment: the values are between -2500 and 2500 from a 16-bit integer. I convert the values by multiplying each by the conversion factor above (the manufacturer suggested this approach to get them in Volt). I want the x-axis in log scale.

Comment: `divide by zero encountered in log10` is almost unavoidable, 'cause with nearly 100 percent probability among the 17,538,000 samples of integer variable signal_v representing a random process and limited in the [-2500, 2500] range there exists one with a zero value;

Comment: `Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part`: axs[1].semilogx(f, signal_dBV_fft) requires the signal_dBV_fft arg to be float [call returns np.asarray(x, float)], while signal_dBV_fft is complex

Comment: start with correcting the `divide by zero encountered in log10` error; here, you have a great chance to understand how your data can be converted to logarithmic representation

Comment: This cannot be answered because the scale factor how ADC converts input voltages into digital output codes is unknown. You need to either measure or calibrate that by feeding in a reference sound with known SPL or feeding in reference signal voltage with known amplitude.

Comment: I have edited the post (see above). The microphone used should be sufficient for this use-case, right?

Comment: Wait, is the `signal_V` an actual time domain signal? If so, then you can't take the logarithm of it before calculating FFT - it doesn't make sense. You can either calculate the RMS level in time domain (might be in dBFS scale) to start with, or you can simply take the FFT of the audio samples, scale to RMS and then apply the logarithm and calibration.

Comment: How far did you put the calibration device? The waveform amplitude seems to vary a lot even by just looking at the waveform, and FFT shows harmonics, what's worse, theres both even and odd harmonics, which may indicate overload/distortion somewhere in the signal path. The amplitude is low though. Wait, how did you end up with plotting the signal in volts to begin with, if that was the part you did not know?

Comment: @Justme It was right over the embedded mic. I converted the units by multiplying each signal (`signal_V = signal_time_domain * (1 / 32768)`). The FFT was just `fft_signal = np.fft.rfft(signal_time_domain)` and then `plt.plot(fft_signal_freq, 2 * np.abs(fft_signal) / n)`

Comment: @Justme i added this part and the other missing ones into the question head above.

Comment: @Tom Two errors. 1) you cannot assume that 32768 means 1V to begin with, because that is what you are trying to figure out to begin with how the sample values convert to voltage, correct? 2) The reference has a manual, it must read at what distance the SPL is 94 dB - this usually is 1 meter, but you cannot simply put it at random distance because the SPL will only be 94 dB at specific distance. You don't need the intermediate conversion to specific voltage if you simply need information how some specific SPL ends up to specific sample values - the voltage is irrelevant.

Comment: I will check the manual. That 32768 means actual 1V comes from the manufacturer. [here](https://community.st.com/t5/other-hardware/unit-of-measure-for-the-mems-imp23absu-microphone/td-p/602993#:~:text=Sorry%2C%20looking%20closer,related%20to%20Pa.)

Comment: @Tom Then your question makes little sense, since then you already know 32768 is 1V and 0dBV. Could it be there is something you don't understand about what dB, dBV, and dB SPL mean? If so, just ask that instead. Also there is an error - if +94 dB SPL is -38 dBV, then 0 dBV is +132 dB SPL.

Comment: I know what dBV is just the $20*log10(\frac{1}{32768} * signal)$ where the signal is the intensitity of the microphone measurement. Then dBSPL has to be calculated by adding the offset of 38 dBV to the actual signal in dBV, right? Is dB of the calibration mic the same as dBSPL?